# need help to shorten my codes in java (netbeans)

Tags: arrays

im having a problem shortening my codes.
Sample Output: 
How many integers will you enter? 
4 
Enter 4 integers, one per line: 
2 
1 
1 
2 
The sum is 6. 
The numbers are: 
2 which is 33.33% of the sum. 
1 which is 16.67% of the sum. 
1 which is 16.67% of the sum. 
2 which is 33.33% of the sum.

the sample output should be this. i already did and perform the task but my codes is very long.

package labexperiment4;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class LabExperiment4 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

double num; 
double num1;
double num2;
double num3;
double num4;
double num5;
double num6;
double num7;
double num8;
double num9;
double num10;
double sum;




System.out.print("How many integers you will enter: ");
num=input.nextInt();

if (num == 1){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +(num1));
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/num1)*100));
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 2){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2;

    System.out.println("The sum is: " +(sum));
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print((+(num2/sum)*100));
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 3){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 4){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    num4=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3+num4;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num4);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num4/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 5){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    num4=input.nextInt();
    num5=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num4);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num4/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num5);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num5/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");

} else if (num == 6) {
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    num4=input.nextInt();
    num5=input.nextInt();
    num6=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num4);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num4/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num5);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num5/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num6);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num6/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 7){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    num4=input.nextInt();
    num5=input.nextInt();
    num6=input.nextInt();
    num7=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num4);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num4/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num5);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num5/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num6);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num6/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num7);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num7/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 8){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    num4=input.nextInt();
    num5=input.nextInt();
    num6=input.nextInt();
    num7=input.nextInt();
    num8=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
     System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
     System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
     System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
     System.out.print(+num4);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num4/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
     System.out.print(+num5);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num5/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
     System.out.print(+num6);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num6/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
     System.out.print(+num7);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num7/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num8);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num8/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 9){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    num4=input.nextInt();
    num5=input.nextInt();
    num6=input.nextInt();
    num7=input.nextInt();
    num8=input.nextInt();
    num9=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num4);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num4/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num5);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num5/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num6);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num6/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num7);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num7/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num8);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num8/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num9);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num9/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} else if (num == 10){
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();
    num4=input.nextInt();
    num5=input.nextInt();
    num6=input.nextInt();
    num7=input.nextInt();
    num8=input.nextInt();
    num9=input.nextInt();
    num10=input.nextInt();
    sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("The Numbers are: ");
    System.out.print(+num1);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num1/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num2);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num2/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num3);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num3/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num4);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num4/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num5);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num5/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num6);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num6/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num7);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num7/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num8);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num8/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num9);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num9/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
    System.out.print(+num10);
    System.out.print(" which is ");
    System.out.print(+((num10/sum))*100);
    System.out.print("%");
    System.out.println(" of the sum");
} 
}
```

}

Comment: You should read about arrays/lists and loops. Do that and you'll be able to shorten your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you, but i asssume it's your homework so it is better to understand the code and trying to do it by yourself.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.print("How many integers you will enter: ");
    int howMany = scan.nextInt();

    double sum = 0;
    int number;

    for(int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter " + (i+1)  + ". number:  ");
        number = scan.nextInt();
        list.add(number);   
        sum += list.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is : " + sum);

    for(int numbers : list)
    {
        System.out.println("Number is " + numbers + " which is " + (numbers/sum) + " of the sum");
    }
}
```